# how can each user get increment and unique id on same table in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

Each time i want to add an invoice, i want to have a unique invoice_id which is an increment number (+1), but the problem is that i have a multiple users app, so i get the error that this invoice_id already exist. how can i customize the ids so each user can have its ids following the latest of same user.

```
class Company(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

class Invoice(models.Model):
company = models.ForeignKey('Company', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
invoice_id = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
```

Comment: Just to clarify, the number should auto-increment per user, not per table right? So each user has a list of consecutive ids?

Comment: yes correct thks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add an last_invoice field in your company record. Then let it do the work for you by adding a function that generates new invoice:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    last_invoice = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def get_invoice(self):
        l_newNum = self.last_invoice + '1' #your number here 
        self.last_invoice = l_newNum
        self.save()
        return l_newNum

class Invoice(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey('Company', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    #you no longer need unique as it will create a mess between companies
    invoice_id = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)

    def save(self):
        self.invoice_id = self.company.get_invoice()
        super(Invoice,self).save()
```

You need to fill in the details here and there, but this should work for you. IDeally I would suggest that the get_invoice is actually used to automatically create Invoice entry for the company, but this would depend on the concrete case you are building.

Comment: Please note that this might create race conditions if 2 invoices are saved at the same time! I'd recommend looking into: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update

Comment: if you are hitting it hard yes, but in most cases the web server will synchronize the calls for you. If we are talking about some really heavy lifting you do need a completely different db design, and I do not think that this fits into the scope of the question

Comment: Well, yes, but I just wanted to raise a comment for when someone else stumbles upon this question. You never know what people might run into

Comment: unfortunetly it doesn t show anything, no invoice_id no error !

Comment: The code snippet I posted is an illustration, based on what you presented. You neither can consider it as a drop-in replacement, nor expect it to work out of the box.

Comment: the problem now is when i want to create a new invoice, the field number doesn t show anything, how i can i add the get_invoice on the invoice_id field. (default value for ex). thx

Comment: you don't need to add it. get_invoice is called when you save the invoice record. Provided you set the company it will use the value stored in the related company record and generate new id. If you wish to initialize the id, set default value for last_invoice in the company record

Comment: the idea is when you create an invoice you get the form to fill, so it needs a value

Comment: if you want the value before setting the other fields, you need to create the invoice first and then use the form to edit the created record. This however goes out of the scope of the problem you posted. So I would suggest to add a new question that adds context.